# How to have Jenkins build all commits in a single branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

I want a Jenkins job to traverse through all commits on a branch in chronological order given a starting commit. I want to run Sonar on all commits on the branch. And Sonar is triggered through Jenkins. Is there an option in Jenkins to achieve this?

It is not an option to invoke sonar from my local machine after checking out commits individually in my workspace.

Answer (score 4):

You could create build which uses the branch/commit hash from which to build as a build parameter. Than create another build jobs that runs `git log --pretty=oneline head...whaterver_commit | awk '{print $1}'` and takes the commit hashes to trigger the first parameterised job.

**Edited:**

Here is an pipeline script example that should work:

```
node('your-jenkins-slave') {
  checkout scm
  def result = sh (script: "git log --pretty=oneline | awk '{print \$1}'", returnStdout: true)
  def hashes = result.split('\n')
  for (int i = 0; i < hashes.size(); i++) {
    def commitHash = hashes[i]
    build job: 'your_job_id', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value:commitHash]]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to work out how can I call the first job repeatedly? I will have a set of commits and I need to trigger a build for each commit. I plan to use the Parametrized trigger plugin.

Comment: I added a code snipped that should work with this. I also used the Pipeline Plugin.